# Overhead of serving pages - JSPs vs. PHP vs. ASPXs vs. C

Tags: http, optimization, ads

I am interested in writing my own internet ad server.

I want to serve billions of impressions with as little hardware possible.

Which server-side technologies are best suited for this task? I am asking about the relative overhead of serving my ad pages as either pages rendered by PHP, or Java, or .net, or coding Http responses directly in C and writing some multi-socket IO monster to serve requests (I assume this one wins, but if my assumption is wrong, that would actually be most interesting).

Obviously all the most efficient optimizations are done at the algorithm level, but I figure there has got to be some speed differences at the end of the day that makes one method of serving ads better than another. How much overhead does something like apache or IIS introduce? There's got to be a ton of extra junk in there I don't need.

At some point I guess this is more a question of which platform/language combo is best suited - please excuse the in-adroitly posed question, hopefully you understand what I am trying to get at.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're going to have a very difficult time finding an objective answer to a question like this. There are simply too many variables:

- Does your app talk to a database? If so, which one? How is the data modeled? Which strategy is used to fetch the data?
- Does your app talk across a network to serve a request (web service, caching server, etc)? If so, what does that machine look like? What does the network look like?
- Are any of your machines load balanced? If so, how?
- Is there caching? What kind? Where does it live? How is cached data persisted?
- How is your app designed? Are you sure it's performance-optimal? If so, how are you sure?
- When does the cost of development outweigh the cost of adding a new server? Programmers are expensive. If reduced cost is your goal with reducing hardware, you'll likely save more money by using a language in which your programmers feel productive.
- Are you using 3rd party tools? Should you be? Are they fast? Won't some 3rd party tools reduce your cost?

If you want some kind of benchmark, Trustleap [publishes challenge results](http://www.trustleap.com/) between their G-Wan server using ANSI C scripts, IIS using C#, Apache with PHP, and Glassfish with Java. I include it only because it attempts to measure the exact technologies you mention. I would never settle on a technology without considering the variables above and more.

Answer (score 1):

**Errata:**

**G-Wan uses ANSI C scripts** (rather than "compiled ANSI C" as explained above)

And it *transparently* turns synchronous (connect/recv/send/close) system calls into asynchronous calls (this is working even with shared libraries).

This can help a great deal to scale with database server requests, posts, etc.